# How to tell which control accessed a method with multiple references?

Tags: c#, winforms, identifier

I have 25 buttons that I've assigned into 1 method (snippet below). I want to be able to grab the clicked button's informations such as tags and name, and set the`.Enabled` property to false. I have this following code;

```
    int picksLeft = 5;
    int value = 100;
    string multiplier;
    string buttonName;

    private void btnPick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //My method with 25 references (buttons)
    {
        for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--)
        {
            if (lblPicks.Text == "Picks Left: " + i)
            {
                picksLeft = i - 1;
            }
        }
        lblPicks.Text = "Picks Left: " + picksLeft.ToString();
        //Get tag string, disable the button.
        //multiplier = buttonName.Tag;
        //Controls[buttonName].Enabled = false;
        //value -= value * Convert.ToDouble(multiplier);
    }
```

Comment: Assuming this method is called as an event handler, the button that raised the event is passed as the `sender` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sender object contains all the information, just cast it to button.
As I remember it should look like this: 
button = sender as button;
Then use it to refer to any of its properties.

I hope it would help.

```
Button btn;

 private void btnPick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //My method with 25 references (buttons)
 {
    for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if (lblPicks.Text == "Picks Left: " + i)
        {
            picksLeft = i - 1;
        }
    }
    lblPicks.Text = "Picks Left: " + picksLeft.ToString();
    btn = sender as Button;
    btn.Enabled = false;
    multiplier = btn.Tag;
    value -= value * Convert.ToDouble(multiplier);
}
```

Comment: `sender as Control;` Exactly what I was looking for, thanks. I added in what I had to do following your instructions as an edit.